# How do I upload images to a slideshow in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, image-upload, media-images

I asked my developer to send over a tutorial on how to upload pictures and banners to the slideshow, and I am not seeing the same information he is.

When I get to the area where I need to browse for a banner, there are no "Browse" buttons. Only a "Create Folder..." button. The screenshots below show what I am having problems with locating the "browse" button.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Flash was used for controls on these upload pages. You may need to enable it for this functionality to work fork you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an ACL issue. Ask your developer if you can use his account or an account with higher levels of permissions to test if you can see this button.